# Create VM in Microsoft Azure using JAVA

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

I want to create VMs in Microsoft Azure using a Java REST API. For this, initially I am getting an access token using Microsoft login credentials by passing below values:

```
grant_type: client_credentials, client_id: {my_client}, client_secret: {my_client_secret}, resource:{http://localhost}
```

Then I am getting a big access key. Then I am calling create VM REST api using this access key. But its Unauthorised error like below.

```
"code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience", 
"message": "The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource 'http://localhost'.
```

It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences 'http://localhost','http://localhost'."

How do you correctly call Microsoft Azure authentication and create a VM using JAVA? Is there any way to achieve authorization through a certificate? What are those steps?

Comment: Try by specifying `https://management.core.windows.net/` as resource instead of `http://localhost`.

Comment: Do we need to give https://management.core.windows.net/ URL under "single sign-on" for Active Directory. What values do we need to give for "APP ID URI" and "REPLY URL" under single-sign-on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might use the incorrect urls for Azure Resource Management.

According to [the offical example in Java for create VM](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/samples/compute/CreateVMExample.java), you can see the urls below in the code comment for requesting the access token.

```
/**
     * Create a VM with VirtualNetwork and storage account
     * within a subscription using a service principal for authentication.
     * To use the sample please set following environment variable or simply replace the getenv call
     * with actual value:
     *
     management.uri=https://management.core.windows.net/
     arm.url=https://management.azure.com/
     arm.aad.url=https://login.windows.net/
     arm.clientid=[your service principal client id]
     arm.clientkey=[your service principal client key]
     arm.tenant=[your service principal tenant]
     management.subscription.id=[your subscription id (GUID)]
     *
     * @param args arguments supplied at the command line (they are not used)
     * @throws Exception all of the exceptions!!
     */
```

You can try to refer to the other example [ServicePrincipalExample.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/samples/authentication/ServicePrincipalExample.java) to check your code whether the urls & ids are correct.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of access token :

When generating token
1) For ARM Resource
Give resource = 
https://management.core.windows.net/

2) For ASM Resource
Give resource =
https://management.azure.com/